# Git hub says "is up to date with all commits from the other branch" but it's not

Tags: github

Git hub tells me "master is up to date with all commits from Bogdan. "
when I try to merge 2 branches, but when I check the branches, I can see that some master lacks some functions from the last commit from Bogdan.
Everything is pushed and up to date with local changes.

Comment: Please, post the commands you are trying to run and the output of each of them.

Comment: @andreybleme  git merge Bogdan
Already up to date.